# How to bind a prop to a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the following component

```
const A = ({prop1,prop2}) => (
    <div>{prop1 + ' ' + prop2}</div>
)
```

How can I bind / create a closure of / curry prop1? In other words what is the right way to write the following such that A gets `{prop1:'prop1!',prop2:'prop2!'}`

```
const B = ({BoundA}) => (
    <div><BoundA prop2 = 'prop2!' /></div>
)

<B A = {<A prop1 = 'prop1!' />} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components are Immutable so once a component is created the props can't be changed. To update props, we have to use `React.cloneElement()` like so

```
const B = ({ BoundA }) => (
 <div>React.cloneElement(BoundA,{prop2:'prop2!'})</div> 
)
```

This solution is similar to acdcjunior's but it doesn't require B to import A. This also makes it possible for B to generically accept components without accepting both the component and an instance of the component

Answer (score 2):

How about just picking up the props and passing down like:

```
<div><A prop1={BoundA.props.prop1} prop2='prop2!' /></div>
```

Example:

```
const B = ({ BoundA }) => (
  <div><A prop1={BoundA.props.prop1} prop2='prop2!' /></div>
)

<B BoundA={<A prop1='prop1!' />} />
```

And, if you want to reuse the `<A />` instance passed in `<B BoundA={<A`, you can't. You won't be able to add props to existing elements.

If you did something like:

```
const B = ({ BoundA }) => {
  BoundA.props.prop2 = 'new prop prop2';
  return <div>{ BoundA }</div>
};
```

You'd get:

> #### TypeError Cannot add property prop2, object is not extensible.

So, if you have several props, your alternative is to use [**`React.cloneElement()`**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

```
const B = ({ BoundA }) => (
  <div>{ React.cloneElement(BoundA, {prop2: 'prop2!' }) }</div>
)

<B BoundA={<A prop1='prop1!' />} />
```

Comment: I think that gets the job done, but if I made a request in the constructor of A I think it would be made twice

Comment: Uhm, did you try it? It appears it doesn't. Try changing `A` to `class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('A instantiated', props.prop1, this)
    console.log('---')
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.prop1 + ' ' + this.props.prop2}</div>;
  }
}`. The constructor is only called when the component is used in a render function to actually render.

Comment: So, I see you edited the answer. Did you get to try the code?